# How to display a 'form in div' in alert box?

Tags: javascript

I want to display a form in a Div, in alert box.

How would i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you meant you want to override `alert(...)` with some `<div>` you have...

**You can NOT...**

If you want to display `<div>` as if it was an alert box:
Read [this](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/) **Excellent** article, that offers an easy way of doing it with a `jQuery` plugin:

> This jQuery plugin aims to replace the basic functionality provided by the standard JavaScript alert(), confirm(), and prompt() functions.
>   ...
>   ...

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/)

---

**Update:**(based on the comment)

O.K. so you want *"a form in a div and I want to display that form in alert box"*
It's can be done with jQuery UI library, it has the *Dialog* widget.

Check it out [**here**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)

Comment: Actually i have a form in a div and i want to display that form in alert box after clicking a link

Comment: @AshuGud. o.k. you could write it in the first place... check the update.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to create a "custome alert box", see something like [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

It requires [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), but it's a very easy to learn javascript library

With jQueryUI's Dialog it's as easy as :

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    create: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).append($("#formID").clone());
    }
});
```

though you can just write the form into the div you use for dialog then you just call that dialog!

for example:

```
<div id="myDialog">
    <form id="frmDialog" action="<?php echo site_url('someContoller/someFunc') ?>" method="post">
        <label for=="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        <label for=="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" />
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#myDialog").dialog({
            // will keep it from opening until called upon
            autoOpen: false,
            // just some effects for opn and close of this "alert" dialog box
            show: "blind",
            hide: "explode",
            // create and tell ok button to submit form, and cancel to close form
            buttons: {
                "OK": function(e) {
                    $("#frmDialog").submit();
                },
                "Cancel": function(e) {
                    $("#myDialog").dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        // will turn button into a pretty button and asign it a click event to opent he dialog
        $("#btnDialog").button().click(function(e) {
            $("#myDialog").dialog("open");
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't override `alert();`, but you can use a third party popup, like jQuery UI's [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).